# Insert comment on pdf using java

Tags: java

I want to insert sticky notes for particular text in existing pdf file using java.i have to search all particular words in pdf and mark it as comment. when i mouse over on comment stored words should be displayed.

can anyone help me on this..

Comment: Sorry, you question is a bit unspecific.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com). You can add an [annotation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Annotation.html) to the PDF.

Comment: Thank u so much.i have used the following code:http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=147.but i want a code for existing pdf.

Comment: Just load the PDF: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);` etc.

Comment: Using PdfReader i can only read the exiting file.but cant modifying.i dont know how to hightlight a particular word in pdf and add annotation for that.can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: i have inserted one comment in first page of existing pdf using pdfstamper.but i have to search a particular word in pdf and mark it as comment.can u suggest me any example program?